# Monitor connected and working but not detected

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, nvidia-graphics-card

I have a PC with an MSI NVIDIA GT710 Graphics card which can feed three monitors via three outputs VGA/HDMI/DVI. I have had them all working in the past but now my central monitor (DVI) is not being detected. This is particularly strange because when the PC is starting up the very first thing I see is the motherboard's ASUS logo on the central monitor! But by the time the machine is showing the windows 10 login screen it will only display graphics on the two outer screens and the centre one is blank. If I go to "Display settings" I only see the two outer monitors and if I press the "Detect" button I just get the message "Didn't detect another display".

Is there some way to force the card to output to all three outputs even if no monitor is detected on one of them? Anything else I could try?

Answer (score 0):

[Specification](https://us.msi.com/Graphics-card/GT-710-2GD3H-LP/Specification)

Graphics Processing Unit = NVIDIA GeForce GT 710

**Maximum Display** = **2**

DVI Connectors = Dual-link DVI-D x 1Max Resolution: 2560 x 1600 @60 Hz

  **(May not match your monitor (?))**

D-Sub Connectors = Dual-link DVI-D x 1Max Resolution: 2560 x 1600 @60 Hz

HDMI Connectors = 1 (version 1.4a) Max Resolution: 4096x2160 @24 Hz

Comment: Never noticed the maximum displays before... but then I'm puzzled as to why it used to work.

Comment: I have no answer to that, maybe it is due to a Windows update.